# USe JSON to store and output radio buttons

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I have this page where a user logs in and they are able to see a list of static tasks that they must accomplish and I added a radio button to each task like this:

```
<div data-role="collapsible-set">
    <div data-role="collapsible">
        <h3>12 Months</h3>
        <div id="task_1" data-role="fieldcontain">
            <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="vertical" data-mini="true">
                <legend></legend>
                <input id="radio3" name="" value="" type="radio">
                <label for="radio3">Begin Research</label>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
```

This same code repeats for all tasks. Using AJAX, how can I get the value for each radio button and save it to the database so that when they log back in they can see the radio buttons they clicked?

Comment: you probably want to have a more detailed example if you want a useful answer. Without details, I would recommend the javascript serialize api http://api.jquery.com/serialize/ to serialize your form

Comment: I see thre parts here: Getting the values, sending them to the server and processing the data on the server (saving them in a DB). With what are you having problems with? Please post the code you have so far and explain where exactly you are stuck. It would also be useful to know which libraries you are using, if any, and whether it is a fixed requirement to send the data as JSON.

Comment: @Youn: That's the jQuery library though, not native JavaScript. You cannot assume that the OP is using it.

Comment: agreed and hence code suggestion. now that there is code, it actually looks like jquery mobile which also has serialize http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a2/experiments/api-viewer/docs/serialize/